# Quickblox incomming message listener for chats

Tags: android, quickblox

I want to show notifications for incomming message when the user is online. 
I know we can get a messagelistener by inheriting QBMessageListener Listener.

But this listener can only be registered with specific room. How can I listen to any incoming chat without joining into all the rooms available in my chatroom.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To be notified when someone writes you a message/starts a chat, please use

QBPrivateChatManager.addPrivateChatManagerListener(QBPrivateChatManagerListener listener) QBPrivateChatManagerListener